# How can I change properties of array of state in redux toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my case:

```
const initialState = {
  users: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "user1",
      email: "uesr1@gmail.com",
      isEnter: false,
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "user2",
      email: "user2@gmail.com",
      isEnter: false,
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "user3",
      email: "user@gmail.com",
      isEnter: false,
    },
  ],
};

const testSlice = createSlice({
  name: "test",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    enterUser(state, action) {
      // const findUser = state.users.find((user) => user.id === action.payload);
      // findUser.isEnter = true;
    },
    exitUser(state, action) {
      // const findUser = state.users.find((user) => user.id === action.payload);
      // findUser.isEnter = false;
    }
});
```

I want to find the object of a specific user through id in `state.users` and change the `isEnter` property.

However, inside the reducer, `state.users` appears as a proxy(not an array), so I cannot use the `Array.prototype.find()`.

So I tried using `current(state.users).find()`, but it was a read-only array, so I couldn't change the `isEnter` property.

What should I do? Help..

Answer (score 0):

Provide id of user as payload.

```
   enterUser(state, action) {
            const user = state.users.find(user => user.id === action.payload);
            state user = state.users.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload).concat([{...user, isEnter: !user.isEnter}]);
     },
```